# How to migrate redmine database to openproject dadabase?

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, redmine, openproject

I would like to migrate redmine 4.4.1 version postgresql database to Openproject 11.1.2(postgresql).

I couldn't find any documentation. I need Step by step documentation

could anyone please help me?

Comment: I would install blank openproject and then make a database compare...

Comment: there are so much different from redmine database and openproject